# Left Folner sequence for a semigroup

Tags: ergodic-theory, semigroups, amenability

Let $0<r<1$ and  $\alpha\in [0, r]\cup \{1\}$. Take $f_{\alpha}:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f_\alpha(x)=\alpha x$. Let $$T=\{f_\alpha: \alpha\in ([0, r]\cup \{1\})\}$$
Is there a Folner sequence for $T$?

A sequence $\{A_n\}_{n\in D}$, where $A_n\subseteq T$ is finite set, is called left folner sequence if and only if for each $t\in T$, the net
$$ \frac{|tA_n\Delta A_n|}{|A_n|}$$
Converges to $0$.(Definition 4.1 in [Density in Arbitrary Semigroups](http://nhindman.us/research/density.pdf) by Hindman and Strauss.)

Comment: Could you please revise your question? Should $f$ be $f_\alpha$? Should $F_n$ be $A_n$? Is $D$ a directed set? How do you define $tA_n$?

Comment: @J.-E.Pin Thanks for your comment, I edited it.